# Trying to sort out a Json ParserError: Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries

Tags: json, logstash

I've got a rsyslog server sending logs to logstash (6.8).  For the (very) vast majority of logs that I receive (windows, unix, etc) everything parses just fine.

```
input {
  codec => json {
    charset => "ISO-8859-1"
    }
  }
}
```

However when I receive some logs (I stress some) for event ID 4688 that contain binary at the end of the log event like the below example - I receive the error:

> Json ParserError: Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object
>   entries

```
 -NoProfile -NonInteractive -EncodedCommand KABOAGUAdwAtAEkAdABlAG0AIAAtAFQAeQBwAGUAIABEAGkAcgBlAGMAdABvAHIAeQAgAC0AUABhAHQAaAAgACQAZQBuAHYAOgB0AGUAbQBwACAALQBOAGEAbQBlACAAIgBhAG4AcwBpAGIAbABlAC0AdABtAHAALQAxADQAMwAzADAAOAA3ADYANQA5AC4AMgA4AC0ANwA0ADQANAA1ADMANgA1ADQAMQA2ADgANwAyACIAKQAuAEYAdQBsAGwATgBhAG0AZQAgAHwAIABXAHIAaQB0AGUALQBIAG8AcwB0ACAALQBTAGUAcABhAHIAYQB0AG8AcgAgACcAJwA7AA==
```

I'm at a loss at how to parse it.  I don't really care about the binary, is there a way for me to chop off a log event after it see's -EncodedCommand before it gets run through a filter?  All other 4688 events parse without any issue and a grok filter (if it makes it past the json parse) passes without issue either.

Comment: So do I understand you right that you want to drop/dismiss all events that contain **-EncodedCommand**?

Comment: not drop unless I have to - but trim everything after -EncodedCommand to prevent the JSON parsing error.